# input type="number" accepts negative values (-) in dev mode but not on production

Tags: html, reactjs, input, user-input, temperature

I have an input type number that accepts temperature for a field in my form. It is in a ReactJs component. It accepts negative values when I try it on dev. For example, I can enter -10, but I cannot do the same on production for the same piece of code. Interestingly on production, if I enter 10 first, and then go back to the first element, I can add a minus sign (-). But I cannot do so if there is no value in the text. What is missing here? Also, why is working on dev but not production?

```
<input
  required="true"
  type="text"
  class={'has-error-' + this.props.errors.includes('loadTemperature') + ' form-control input-lg'}
  id="load_temperature"
  name="loadTemperature"
  placeholder="Enter temperature"
  onChange={e => this.props.updateLoadDetails('loadTemperature', e)}
  onBlur={e => this.props.onBlur(e)}
  defaultValue={this.props.loadDetails.loadTemperature}
/>
```

Comment: Right there in your code: `type="text"`.  That is _not_ an input with a type number. If it really were an input with a type number, you could simply set the `min` attribute on the input to `0`

Comment: @Ted But it is an input type number, negative should be accepted. It works fine on dev, just not on prod. I agree converting type to text would solve this, but then I would need additional validations to make sure to accept only integers.

Comment: I was quoting your posted code. Post the code that is not working. I am _not_ suggesting you change it to a text input.

Comment: @Ted The above code is the code that is giving me troubles. As I've mentioned above, this exact code works fine in the development environment, but the same code does not work in the production environment.

Comment: Back to my point that **is not** an `<input type="number"`, that **is** an `<input type="text"`.

Comment: @Ted I'm just curious to know why is it working fine on dev mode?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for us to answer your question with the posted code. If you can provide a functioning example of the problem we may be better able to assist.